# nginx - restrict direct URL access to https but can be redirected from http

Tags: security, http, nginx, https

Being looking for similar problem but can't find proper solution.

On nginx web server I have web site listening on 443 which I don't want to be accessible from url (if I type https://my.server/foo, to give 403), but only to be acceptable if it is redirected from 80 port, where proper login has taken place.

I read about valid_referers and tried:

```
valid_referers none blocked server_names
        localhost ip.of.server;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 403;
        }
```

and

```
valid_referers server_names
        localhost ip.of.server;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            return 403;
        }
```

since I wasn't sure what is the right syntax, but all was completely ignored.

What am I doing wrong, and is this the good way to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Mirko

EDIT:
Solution was to place the valid_referers before rewrite:
    location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9=\?]+)$ {

```
    valid_referers server_names http://ip.of.ser.ver;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }

    rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
}
```

Comment: You want something weird. Login on http and redirect to https is exactly opposite to what you should do.

Comment: Ok thanks for tip, I can try to switch between those, and then how should I restrict direct http url access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax should work:

```
valid_referers server_names http://your.domain;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
}
```

But what are you trying to accomplish with this? The referer header is very easy to inject in to the request. If this is a security measure, it's obviously a very insecure one.

Comment: I read that refer header is easy to fake, but it is not a problem, if it will stop 99% of people directly accessing from url. Problem is that this code is still beiong ignored, or my browsers are somehow caching...i can still access directly from url and redirected from php after login

Comment: That should work. Inspect the network console of your browser and see if the browser is sending the Referer header in request headers.

Comment: it is working now, i had a rewrite rule before referer check. When I switched it it is ok  now